# performance issues with Apache as reverse proxy and an ajax-heavy jsf application

Tags: apache, jsf, nginx, push, atmosphere

I am currently developing a jsf application (running in jboss7 with primefaces 3.5 and push via primepush which basically uses the atmosphere framework to hide all the transport specific stuff  behind a layer of abstraction)

As long as i am running just jboss the application works fine and responds quickly as would be expected. However when deploying this to production where jboss runs behind an Apache reverse proxy several problems appear.

The first problem being that Apache seems to kill the long-polling connection which causes the client to miss out on push messages (even after configuring atmosphere to use a broadcast cache). I currently work around that by periodically refreshing the whole page when user is idle, although this smells really bad..

Second, Apache seems to really slow down the whole application. Watching the Apache error log i am seeing a lot of messages like *error reading chunk* (will post the exact message later as i am currently writing this post on the go with my smartphone). Lot's of digging around in the atmosphere documentation and trying out different broadcasters did mit change this in any way.

My question would be this: would i be better off by using nginx, especially in the context of push via long polling?

I know i have given only little detail, i will edit this post later when at home ;)

Answer (score 1):

just so this topic gets closed: if you have an atmopshere-based application running behind an apache reverse proxy, be sure to set the TTL parameter for the proxypass directive. setting this parameter to 5 worked for me, apache now discards old connections fast enough so it doesn't run out of worker threads.